# Unable to connect to http://localhost:8091/index.html

Tags: couchbase

I have just installed CouchBase Server Enterprise v2.0.0 using the setup.exe on my Windows 7 64bit machine and supposedly the Browser based Console should appear automatically after installation but all i am getting is
Unable to Connect:

```
**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8091.**
```

The CouchBase service is running when I check?
I have uninstalled and reinstalled a couple of times now?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: in a cmd prompt run "netstat -a -b -p tcp" and check which port/s your couchbase server is using

Comment: Thanks for the tip however I dont see couchbase there?

Comment: never used couchbase myself, but if there is no listening socket for the couchbase server ( no idea what exe name that would be ) that would suggest to me that either couchbase isnt running, or it is unable to open the server socket, have you checked the windows firewall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably hitting a known issue related to IP address acquisition during startup of Couchbase Server.

I have documented a work around here: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-to-do-if-your-couchbase-server.html

As stated in the blog post it will be fixed in the 2.0.1 release