# Couchbase 2.2 - Cannot connect to console after installation

Tags: console, connection, couchbase

I have installed Couchbase 2.2.0 for Windows 7 64 bits. I installed it using the default options. The service gets installed and I can stop/start or restart it without errors. However, I cannot connect to the management console on port 8091.

I've found some posts on how to deal with this but they all relate to older versions of couchbase and reference files/options I can't find in version 2.2 (for example this post : [Unable to connect to http://localhost:8091/index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137996/unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8091-index-html)).

When I try netstat -an -p tcp I can't see any service listening on port 8091 so I suspect something goes wrong during startup.

Looking in the couchbase log in /var/lib/couchbase/logs I can see some errors but they don't make sense to me.

```
    [error_logger:error,2014-02-11T17:13:16.536,babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:log_msg:76]** Generic server <0.233.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {die,{abnormal,3}}
** When Server state == {state,ns_server,5000,
                               {1392,135189,391066},
                               undefined,infinity}
** Reason for termination == 
** {abnormal,3}

[ns_server:debug,2014-02-11T17:13:16.536,babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1:<0.235.0>:supervisor_cushion:init:39]starting ns_port_server with delay of 5000
[error_logger:error,2014-02-11T17:13:16.536,babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:log_report:72]
=========================CRASH REPORT=========================
  crasher:
    initial call: supervisor_cushion:init/1
    pid: <0.233.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {abnormal,3}
      in function  gen_server:terminate/6
    ancestors: [child_ns_server_sup,ns_babysitter_sup,<0.58.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.73.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 2584
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 2365
  neighbours:
```

The windows firewall is running but, since I installed the same version of couchbase on another machine with the same Windows version without troubles I can't imagine that the firewall is causing this trouble.

I'm out of options though, I have no idea why I can't get this to work.

In the meantime, I have uninstalled 2.2 and tried falling back to 2.1 (with the same result) and moving forward to 2.5 (with the same result). In all cases I turned of antivirus software and stopped the Windows firewall to eliminate this cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the nice people at Couchbase.com, the problem has been solved. 
Please refer to :

https://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-10245

https://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-8760

The solution is to reinstall couchbase in a location without spaces in the path. Due to a bug, spaces in the installation path lead to trouble.

Comment: Wow, terrible bug considering the default installation path is in "Program Files".  This bug is still active as of version 2.5.1.