# Couchbase post-installation blank screen on localhost:8091/index.html

Tags: couchdb

I have just installed Couchbase Server v.3.0.1. Right after intallation, I am redirected to `localhost:8091/index.html`. The **page is blank** on Firefox (error 500 in console), Chrome. IE says "cannot view the page" (error 500).
According to suggestion from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137996/unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8091-index-html) I have run:
`netstat -a -b -p tcp` and get:

```
...
 No information is available about the property
  TCP   0.0.0.0:8080    my_host_name:0    LISTENING
 [httpd.exe]
  TCP   0.0.0.0:8091    my_host_name:0    LISTENING
 [ismagent.exe]
...
```

Installation path without whitespaces:
`E:\programy\Couchbase\Server\bin>`
Testing server...

```
 > cbworkloadgen.exe -n localhost:8091
error: could not access REST API: localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets; please check source URL, server status, username (-u) and password (-p); exception: ''
```

Comment: Output of `netstat` shows that imsagent.exe is listening on port 8091. IMS (Intel Services Manager) agent is not Windows core service. Killing that process solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of `netstat` shows that `imsagent.exe` is listening on port 8091. IMS (Intel Services Manager) agent is not Windows core service. Killing that process solved the problem.